# No qualifying bean of type is defined

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to teach myself spring Java annotation configuration with a very simple example. But I get the error NoSuchBeanDefinitionException.

My Pom file has:

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"     
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0    
 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>SpringDemo</groupId>
<artifactId>SpringDemo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

<!-- JavaConfig need this library -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
    <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Then my config class has:

```
 package org.jorkata;


 @Configuration
 public class JavaConfig {

  @Bean
   public Triangle triangle(){
     return new Triangle();
  }

}
```

And I've defined a simple class in my package:

```
 package org.jorkata;


 public class Triangle {

  private int val;

    public int getVal() {
       return val;
   }

     public void setVal(int val) {
        this.val = val;
     }

   public void returnVal(){
      System.out.println(getVal());
   }

}
```

In my application class I've got:

```
 package org.jorkata;

  import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
 import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;


public class DrawingApplication {

public static void main(String[] args){

    ApplicationContext ctx = 
              new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(JavaConfig.class);

    Triangle triangle1 = (Triangle) ctx.getBean(Triangle.class);
    Triangle tr = ctx.getBean(Triangle.class);
    }
 }
```

And I get the error thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.jorkata.Triangle] is defined

Comment: I was following the tutorial from here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_java_based_configuration.htm. They don't annotate the class. Only in their config class. So I did the same

Comment: @almasshaikh annotating with _what_? `@Bean` is sufficient.

Comment: Have you turned on `Spring` trace logging to see what's going on?

Comment: plz show the whole code, not just parts of classes. maybe you messed with imports?

Comment: @Boris the Spider No I haven't

Comment: @ piotrek I've pasted all the code

Comment: Well, I think you know what I'm going to suggest you do then.

Comment: @user3793865 it can't be all the code. there is no imports for `@Configuration` and `@Bean`

Comment: What imports do I need for them? It doesn't complain..

Comment: @user3793865, your imports are fine. Turn logging on as Boris suggested. You may edit your post to include the logs.

Comment: Sorry guys. I've actually realized that I have a class in my project where I implement BeanPostProcessor interfaces and this somehow interferes with the JavaConfig. So when I removed the BeanPostProcessor class it worked. Thank you